# Правильно ли организована структура класса?

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, aiogram, декоратор

Для написания бота на языке Python используется библиотека aiogram. Для создания обработчика сообщений в этой библиотеке используется декоратор объекта Dispatcher, который мы получаем из объекта класса Bot.

Я хочу описать класс BotEngine, через который буду взаимодействовать с функционалом бота. Я сохраняю в одном из полей объекта класса BotEngine объект диспетчера. Метод объекта диспетчера message_handler должен быть декоратором для моего обработчика сообщений. Подскажите, данная организация класса уместна? Правильно ли используется декоратор в данном случае?

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

class TgBotEngine:
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.bot = Bot(token)
        self.dp = Dispatcher(self.bot)

        self.init_handlers()

        executor.start_polling(self.dp, skip_updates=True)

    def init_handlers(self):
        @self.dp.message_handler()
        async def echo(message: types.Message):
            await message.answer(message.text)
```

Comment: Я думаю использовать классы для телеграм бота на aiogram не самая полезная затея

Comment: Использование декораторов внутри функций - это скорее антипаттерн.